# Package a crm unmanaged solution for deployment

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to Dynamics CRM 2011 Development and Deployment.But recently, I need to upgrade changed web resource files (IE. Html,java script) only into the QA Environment.

The following is what I do this, currently.

1. export an unmanaged solution for webresource files to be updated.
2. use solution packager to extract the solution zip file into a working folder.
3. make code changes to web resource files.
4. pack the working folder into an unmanaged zip for deployment.

Would you please give me some suggestions about best practices to this.

1. How to package web resource files into an import unmanaged zip file?Any other tools?
2. Is there a vs template or do I need a vs solution to hold all the changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to your question per se.  However since you are working with an unmanaged solution the most straightforward approach would be to load the solution into your UAT environment and modify the web resource files directly in the solution on UAT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But how do you pack web resource files in a vs solution into an unmanaged crm solution zip file for deployment?

Comment: I am not aware of any tools specifically designed for this purpose.  I am also interested if someone else knows more.  Out of curiosity what is your reason for manually modifying the resource files instead of modifying them through the CRM interface?

Comment: I need to change a few places in a javascript file and a html file. I guess that it can be done programmatic via CRM interface.